# Wordpress post got modified without user logged In. What are the possibilities?

Tags: php, wordpress, security

Just figuring out the possibilities on how the wordpress blog could have been modified without author context and login.

This are the possibilities that could have happened.

1. User login got hacked by password disclose and someone might have taken the advantage of it ?
2. User login got hacked and post got modified ? What can be the hacking possibility of getting user login details ?
3. Server details got hacked and with the help of script. The post were modified ? What are the possibilities that server got hacked ?
4. How did the hacker know which database and DB password to target to modify the post ?

Can anyone tell me what can be the possibilities ?

Comment: There is N number of ways that hackers could find your username and password. You should have a very strong password and install security plugins like WordFence, WPSpamSheild .. etc to make your WP site secure.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Thamaraiselvam mentioned in his comment, there are (N * possibility) lot of possibilities for this to happen.

You cannot figure out all of them. And the good news is, you don't have to.

Even though we all are aware of a lot of security vulnerabilities in the internet world, we do not hold all the responsibilities to keep every site we use a safe box. You just need to be sure that you can trust the website you use. Most of them take care of the serious issues that we may not even aware of.

All you need to do is a few easy steps.

- Have a strong password.   If possible use the 2-step verification of 
  your choice.
- Do not share your password.
- Ensure you don't save your passwords in the browsers
- Uncheck the *keep me signed in* checkbox (Unless no one else uses
  your computer)
- And make sure you save your work before you leave. Some times we
  leave our drafts helpless without saving and wonder where has it gone
  when we come back later. It happens.

If you are hundred percent sure that none of this is a problem and you have definitely been hacked, then just write to the support with whatever input you have. They will help you out.